# Which route should i take for web hosting?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am setting up a small website sort of like an online portfolio. I made the mistake of signing up for shared-web hosting before asking if they supported stored procedures which took me half the day to figure out they didn't.

Basically i'm looking for a site that offers me PHP5.4+/ Mysql 5.5 + with support for triggers/stored procedures/ and if possible MyphpAdmin 3.5.1.

I also have a domain name I already registered and which I would like to use.

What is my best option to look for hosting provider which offers this functionality or to setup a VPS?

Comment: http://hetzner.de - I pay $10 monthly and get my own VPS with 512mb ram and 20gb hdd

Comment: Shopping and subjective question is off topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is even a valid question for SO and answers where people simply give the name of some hosting company, in my opinion, do not belong here either. There are literally thousands of hosting companies out there, some are more well known, others, not so much. Some provide great service, others don't. Whatever one you are looking at, I would always suggest you check out reviews. Either search directly into your search engine of choice or use a site such as [WHT](http://www.webhostingtalk.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPS is always a good Option , but the only issue associated with setting up a VPS is COST , do you have that much of budget to afford that, then yes , you should go for VPS , alternatively Shared Hosting is also not an issue unless everything required by you is supported. Prepare a list of all the requirements like versions etc, and then compare the products available . Also please be aware of some issues with shared hosting like,

1. No Logs will be shared
2. Frequent restarts , will force downtimes almost daily for 2-3 mins
3. No version upgrades
4. Shared memory pool , sometimes can be issue if someother's app is not working fine and bringing server down again and again
5. You will have to make sure that you dont put any sensitive info in logs as they might be compromised.

Comment: Note that not all shared hosting do not share logs, some shared host does. And while many shared hosting sites have issues with reliability and overselling, a good shared host should not pose much issues for personal or low traffic commercial sites. Also while most shared hosting sites do not do version upgrade, some provide the necessary tools and support to allow you to install and compile your own local copy of any software you're using.

Comment: @LieRyan Yes i agree with you , but the problem with shared hosting is , whenever you call them up regarding an issue the first point they come up with is "This is a shared hosting, and such things are expected" Like few days back, i had some unexpected activtiy on my web app and when trying to find out i couldnt see any issues on my logs , so i asked them to share the stdout but they denied

Comment: from what I understand on a VPS you can have whatever version of MYSQL/PHP you want?

Comment: @Undermine2k VPS is like having a physical machine dedicated for you only thing is its logical not physical , yes you can install any software of your own choice unless it voilates any copyright or legal contracts.

Comment: @Akash: on most php based hosting that uses CGI (or its variants) or mod_php, the stdout is what is sent to the user and is never logged even on VPS or own the hardware, unless you prearranged it to be logged yourself in php which will really quickly spend your disk space and kills performance. Are you referring to a non-php framework? since otherwise your stdout log request does not make sense.

Comment: @LieRyan Yeah , my app is a java based application which runs on JVM.its logs are sent to sysout file , and hence the issue,though u can have your own logs , but there was some issue which didnt got captured in logs :( :(

Comment: @Undermine2k: VPS is usually implemented as virtual machine. On a VPS you have root (administrator) access to your virtual machine and it gives you **a lot** of flexibility. The starting price for VPS is a fair bit higher than shared hosting though, so that's something to keep in mind. Also, keep in mind that shared hosting generally do not count the memory usage of the OS, shared web server, and shared database server against your quota, while on a VPS, they invariably do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I was trying to decide what hosting company to go with, I took to Google.

From what I learned, GoDaddy is terrible unless your website consists of kitten pictures, and a hosting company like HostGator is awesome (to be fair, I am using them now).

Lifehacker has a post on their top 5 (http://lifehacker.com/5911651/five-best-web-hosting-companies)

> Dreamhost  27.51%  (1,092 votes)
>
> Hostgator  25.02%  (993 votes)
>
> Bluehost  25.12%  (997 votes)
>
> Linode  9.65%  (383 votes)
>
> A Small Orange  12.7%  (504 votes)
>
> Total Votes: 3,969

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good VPS with a company that provides EXCEPTIONAL support i'de go with **Servint**. They are expensive but I like how I don't have to deal with anything hosting related because they will take care of it through support tickets very quickly - keeps my clients happy. Price is kind of steep though compared to other comparable plans (hardware comparable, not the support) - starts at $49/month

Answer (score 0):

Simple compares the hosting services.

Check it out https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hosting+comparison&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

See them and find the best